# Message Size Quota Issue

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I have a WCF service that returns a structure containing a couple of int arrays that all combined would not exceed 2500 values. When I go to test this service I get the error below:

**The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.**

which I think should not come up in the first place. Am I missing something here?
Maybe it helps you to know I am executing this service from a WCF library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place where you need to work on is the web config, you need to add service behaviours where you can set the size of data. For example like this,

```
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

if that does not work, post your web config here.Hope it helps.